# Remover a numeração de linhas e colunas do DataFrame de uma Matriz

Tags: python, pandas, matriz, dataframe

Estou fazendo um programa que lê uma tabela em CSV e tranforma em matriz no python usando pandas, eu consegui tranforma-la porém o DataFrame numerou as linhas e colunas e eu desejo apaga-las. Segue a foto, o que esta em vermelho é o que eu quero que retire, ou pelo menos não apareça.

```
import pandas as pd

df_cronograma=pd.read_csv('cronograma.csv', sep=';',header=None)
df_custohora=pd.read_csv('custohora.csv', sep=';',header=None)
matriz_cronograma =df_cronograma.values
matriz_custohora =df_custohora.values


df1 = pd.DataFrame(matriz_cronograma)
print(df1)
df2= pd.DataFrame(matriz_custohora)
print(df2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema está no header=None. Remova esta parte do seu código. Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os números da horizontal estão aparecendo porque você usou `header=None`

Mude para

```
df_cronograma=pd.read_csv('cronograma.csv', sep=';')
df_custohora=pd.read_csv('custohora.csv', sep=';')
```

Já os números da vertical, são o índice.

Para imprimir sem o índice, faça:

```
sem_indice = df_cronograma.to_string(index=False)

print(sem_indice)
```

Comment: Consegui!! Muito Obrigada !! :)